# ASP.NET MVC - where to place 'normal' objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

In ASP.NET 4.0 MVC, I wish to make a series of small objects to store data I am reading from a database. I am not sure all would qualify as models and some are being made just because I am used to tucking things away in classes of their own in traditional OOP.

The auto generated directory tree doesn't have an obvious place to put such classes. Where, if they are made at all, do they go? Am I misunderstanding how MVC is meant to be implemented?

Comment: The autogenerated directory structure is just a *suggestion*, not a requirement (well, not always, the views are looked up by convention etc., but for models - it doesn't matter). You can add other directory/directories you want - as long as it makes sense, there isn't anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

As you are reading data from the database into your POCOs, I would argue that these classes would logically be put in the Models folder.

Although there is no strict requirement for the default folder structure in MVC and you are free to build your own.